# Use proxy with wget on the fly

Tags: proxy, wget, http-proxy

I know that if I want to use a proxy with `wget`, I have to edit `/etc/wgetrc` or `~/.wgetrc` file and set there the proxy address and port.

What I want to know if is there any option to use `wget` and use a proxy BUT without editing any config file.

That's all. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the proxy settings via the environment, e.g.:

```
https_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:3128 wget http://www.example.com
```